# Pandas plot cumulative sum of counters over time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a following dataframe:

```
    Joined      User ID
0   2017-08-19  user 182737081
1   2017-05-07  user 227151009
2   2017-11-29  user 227306568
3   2016-05-22  user 13661634
4   2017-01-23  user 220545735
```

I'm trying to figure out how to plot user growth over time. I figured the best way is to plot a cumulative sum. I put together a simple code:

```
tmp = members[['Joined']].copy()
tmp['count'] = 1
tmp.set_index('Joined', inplace=True)
```

This produces the following `cumsum`:

```
            count
Joined  
2017-08-19  1
2017-05-07  2
2017-11-29  3
2016-05-22  4
2017-01-23  5
```

Now when I try to plot this using `tmp.plot()` I get something super weird like this, uh:

[image: cumulative sum as plotted by pandas]

1. I genuinely have no idea what is this plot actually displaying (this looks like some kind of cumulative delta trend line?)
2. How do I plot cumulative user growth over time

The version of pandas I'm using: `pandas (0.20.3)`

In case you are curious whether the length of the series is the same as the highest count:

```
tmp.cumsum().max() == len(tmp)

count  True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems like you need `sort_index`, then `cumsum`  , then `plot`

```
#tmp.index=pd.to_datetime(tmp.index)

tmp.sort_index().cumsum().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S. This answer is really helpful. How would you plot this if the datetime column is not the index?

Comment: @SOK you can set it as index , like df.set_index('date')['col1').cumsum().plot()

Comment: anybody knows the same trick but in seaborn?